# Cant connect to Haproxy load balancer from Rebus

Tags: rabbitmq, load-balancing, haproxy, rebus

I'm using a rabbitmq ha cluster with the ha-proxy load balancer. Now I'm trying to connect to my load balancer from rebus but I don't know how to setup the connectionstring for rebus.
 When I connect to the nodes individually by their connection string it works well (eg:amqp://test:test@10.182.40.68:5672 ). 
Only when I modify the connectionstring to use the load balancer it does not work. My load balancer connectionstring is amqp://rabbit.chathuri.local:5670 (but I tried amqp://test:test@rabbit.chathuri.local:5670 and amqp://test:test@rabbit.chathuri.local connection strings as well, they also didnt work. But My load balancer is working as I can ping rabbit.chathuri.local). Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's really not enough information to say something "didn't work."  You sent a request, you got either a timeout or some kind of error response, and there should have at a minimum been a log entry created by HAProxy.  What are these trying to tell you?